# android alarm app with snooze button

Tags: android

```
//MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1, b2, b3;
    TextView t1, t2;
    int date, month, year, hour, min;
    Calendar calendar;
    Date date1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pt);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pd);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sa);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        calendar.set(year, month, date);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new                                   TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
                        t1.setText(i + " : " + i1);
                    }
                };
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, onTimeSetListener,
                        hour, min, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        t2.setText(i2 + "-" + (i1 + 1) + "-" + i);
                    }
                };
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, onDateSetListener,
                        year, month, date);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener1 = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
                        Calendar cal = calendar.getInstance();
                        Calendar cal1 = (Calendar) cal.clone();
                        cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);
                        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, i1);
                        cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        if (cal1.compareTo(cal) <= 0) {
                            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                        }
                        Long time = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
                        setAlarm(time);
                    }
                };
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog1 = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, onTimeSetListener1,
                        hour, min, false);
                timePickerDialog1.show();


         }
            });}
            public void setAlarm(Long targetcal){
            AlarmManager alarmManager =        (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReciever1.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", targetcal);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 9, intent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP ,targetcal, pendingIntent );
        }
        }
//MyReciever1

public class MyReciever1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Vibrator vibrator;
    Button b1, b2;
    Long cal2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_reciever1);
        vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(600000);
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        cal2 = intent1.getLongExtra("key",0);
        b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              vibrator.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        });
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.snooze);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                vibrator.cancel();
                mainActivity.setAlarm(cal2+1000);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

/*i have made an button to pick time and set alarm in android once the alarm sets off another activity opens up with snooze button and stop button my stop is working but on clicking snooze application is crashing*/

Comment: Do you have some crash info?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: practices.rajat.com.alarmdemo, PID: 3006
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
                      at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5035)
                      at practices.rajat.com.alarmdemo.MainActivity.setAlarm(MainActivity.java:98)
                      at practices.rajat.com.alarmdemo.MyReciever1$2.onClick(MyReciever1.java:39)

Comment: studio is showing this message

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this code :

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
vibrator.cancel();
mainActivity.setAlarm(cal2+1000);
finish();
```

`Activity.getSystemService()` requires a properly initialized Context and you cannot use an Activity as a Context until `onCreate()`.

System services not available to Activities before `onCreate()`.

creating an instance of Activity with a new tag won't let you go through with its lifecycle that it supposed to.

You can launch your Activity by setting up a bundle, pass it with Intent, initiate a startActivity and finally check the bundle value in Activity.